# Deadbolt authorization based on parameters

Tags: scala, playframework, deadbolt-2

I am testing Deadbolt in a Scala Play Application. My controller methods look something like this:

```
def getProject(projectId: Int) = actionBuilder.RestrictAction("user").defaultHandler()  {
    authRequest =>
    //retrieves project
}
```

In this case, I only want the user to be authorized to get the project if the `projectId` belongs to this user. Other more complex cases involve multiple parameters both from the query string and/or the post body.

From what I understand, the approach here would be to pass the parameters to a `DynamicResourceHandler` and then handling the permissions for each case individually. It is feasible, but I was expecting a bit more support from Deadbolt for this use case. What is the best approach to authorize a request based on the parameters received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deadbolt stays fairly neutral to avoid forcing developers into a specific style, but in this case you can use the `meta` argument to pass the information into the constraint.  The definition is

```
  object DynamicAction {

    def apply(name: String, meta: Option[Any] = None): DynamicAction.DynamicActionBuilder = DynamicActionBuilder(name, meta)

    case class DynamicActionBuilder(name: String, meta: Option[Any] = None) extends DeadboltActionBuilder {

      override def apply[A](bodyParser: BodyParser[A])(block: AuthenticatedRequest[A] => Future[Result])(implicit handler: DeadboltHandler) : Action[A] =
        deadboltActions.Dynamic(name, meta, handler)(bodyParser)(block)
    }
  }
```

so your controller function will look something like this

```
def getProject(projectId: Int) = actionBuilder.DynamicAction(name = "checkProject", meta = Some(projectId)).defaultHandler()  {
    authRequest =>
    //retrieves project
}
```

This will get a `DynamicResourceHandler` (I've come to hate that name, I may change it in some future version) and invoke your implementation of this function

```
  def isAllowed[A](name: String,
                   meta: Option[Any] = None,
                   deadboltHandler: DeadboltHandler,
                   request: AuthenticatedRequest[A]): Future[Boolean]
```

You will need to use `asInstanceOf` for the `meta` value.

For more complex requirements, you can pass whatever you have assembled the data into (a case class or map, for example) as the `meta` argument.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was sort of the way I was thinking to do it yeah. I also read about using deadbolt in routes instead of the controller, but I guess it would be harder for me to access parameter values there right?

Comment: Indeed - in the routes, you can only hard-code the meta.  Alternatively, you can parse the URL yourself to get the value, but that's already becoming pretty heavy.